# Why does the Matlab Profiler say there is a bottleneck on the 'end' statement of a 'for' loop?

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, profiling, profiler

So, I've recently started using Matlab's built-in profiler on a regular basis, and I've noticed that while its usually great at showing which lines are taking up the most time, sometimes it'll tell me a large chunk of time is being used on the `end` statement of a `for` loop.

Now, seeing as such a line is just used for denoting the end of the loop, I can't imagine how it could use anything other than a trivial amount of processing.

I've seen a specific version of this question asked on [matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/281822), but a consensus didn't seem to be reached.

EDIT: Here's a minimal example of this problem:

```
for i =1:1000
    x = 1;
    x = [x 1];
    % clear x;
end
```

Even if you uncomment the `clear`, the `end` line still takes up a lot of computation (about 20%), and the `clear` actually increases the absolute amount of computation performed by the end line.

Comment: "It's *probably* a preallocation issue. Though you didn't post your code so it's kind of hard for us to analyze it."

Comment: I didn't post code because I'm wondering about the general case, though I could post a case or to if the concreteness would help. And, if it is always a preallocation issue, why doesn't the profiler point to the line that does the allocation rather than the 'end' line?

Comment: @zergylord: Please post a minimal example that reproduces the problem. You don't have to post your entire code here. Otherwise, it is hard for us to try it out and we certainly don't have the time to fiddle around and come up with an example that will recreate the problem.

Comment: If your Matlab loop is operating on arrays, the endfor may be deallocating space used by the loop body, but not necessary for the next loop iteration.  Just a thought.

Comment: I've noticed this before, and got the feeling that they lump a whole load of time which can't be allocated to specific lines of code onto the `end`. Deallocation would make sense though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I've seen this in my code, it's been the deallocation of large temporaries created in the loop.  Each new variable created in the loop is deallocated at the `end`.

Comment: That seems likely given my experience with Matlab.

Comment: So could you alleviate it with an explicit dealloc of variables with `clear var1`?

Comment: @Marcin, this sounds like a good thing the OP could test: if he adds a clear just before the end, he'll see where all the time is being spent...?

Comment: @Marcin Thanks for the idea, but I just tried it to no avail :(

Comment: @Marcin So turns out the end line was freeing memory and then reaccolating it. Apparently there is an undocumented command 'profile -memory on' that allows you to see this kinda thing in your profile results

Comment: @zergylord Thanks, found an article about it: [Undocumented profiler options](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/undocumented-profiler-options/)